# How to protect a digital directory but allow downloads?

Tags: cartthrob, htaccess, security

First time setting up a digital purchases online and would like some pointers/tips on how to protect the directory where all the digital items are stored so someone can't access the file directly like: `http://domain.com/some/digital/file.zip`?

I'm using CartThrob, so I will either use the `get_download_link` or `download_file_form` tags which will handle link protection & obfuscation.

I just want to make sure I have all my ducks in a row. Thanks!

#### Update

I have directory browsing turned off with `.htaccess` rules, so this fixes listing any files. I saw a couple solutions with adding rules to the directory, but wasn't sure if this would allow CT tags to access the file since I can't access it over the browser:

```
Order Deny, Allow
Deny from all
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We keep all of our downloadable files above web root, so they're not directly accessible, similar to this setup:

```
/public_html
/system
/files
```

And of course, we use [Link Vault](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/link-vault) to obfuscate, protect against hot linking, and track the downloads.

Comment: Storing the files outside of web root, IMO, is the only reliable soliution. I believe CartThrob comes with its own tool to serve the files, but you may also consider separate file-serving add-ons, like Link Vault that Ryan has mentioned, or [Protected Links](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/protected-links)

Answer (score 0):

If you've obfuscated your links using CartThrob's tags, I typically just include a blank `index.html` file in any files/assets directories, as seems to be the EE convention. Then that's displayed instead of a directory index.

Comment: Mark, thanks for the input. I updated my question.